# What is the Gradle analog of CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm developing an Android application, containing native code. I run `javac` to generate JNI headers.

I'd like to programmatically determine destination directory for those JNI headers in order to put them near modules they belong to.

What is the best way to do it?

In CMake I would simply put something like `-h ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/headers` to javac command line, but it is Gradle.

Currently my module's `build.graddle` contains following lines

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs += ["-h", "app/build/headers"]
    }
}
```

Here, `"app"` is the name of the module. This code creates `app/build/headers` directory and the header file in it.

If I omit it, then, `build/headers` is created one level upper, along with `app` directory.

How can I get that `"app"` programmatically? I hope, this would allow me to move those instructions to the project's `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `project.getBuildDir()`

I've also found that I can remove `gradle.projectsEvaluated`: help for `tasks` says that that object holds all tasks for this project.

Now I have in module's `build.gradle` :

```
def JNI_header_path = new File(project.getBuildDir(), "headers")

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += ["-h", JNI_header_path]
}

...
android {
...
    defaultConfig { 
    ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DJNI_INCLUDE_DIR="+JNI_header_path
            }
        }

...
}
```

And in module's CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

I've also found some mismatches in DSL. Android studio calls it a "module", but Gradle calls it a "project". And Android Studio calls a "Project" some bigger entity that encloses several modules.